# Is it possible to make a "class" runtime?

Tags: c#, list, class, object

For the backend of a website, I need to fetch certain datacolumns from a database, depending on which sitesettings the user has. 
So there is no way of knowing which columns I will need beforehand.

Is there any way I can make a list of "objects" containing only the different types I need to return to the frontend?

For example:

The class students is stored in the database:

```
Students
{
string name;
int age;
double averageGrade;
string class;
Student bestFriend;
}
```

Let's say the user on the site wants to see only the student's name and best friend, how can I put those in an object, and put those objects in a list?

```
exampleStudent {name, bestFriend};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at `ExpandoObject`; something like that: `dynamic exampleStudent = new ExpandoObject(); exampleStudent.name = "bla-bla-bla";`

Comment: Why not a dictionary of objects with the name of the properties as keys ?

Comment: It works with the dictionary but I'm going to look into those dynamic objects too because it's a lot of hassle. Thanks to the both of you!

Comment: Going to go with the dictionary after all, @Vincent if you want to put it as an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to store the properties using a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, object> student = new Dictionary<string, object>();
student["name"] = "Alex";
```